# How to split data by months and have each month inserted separatedly using Excel + Power Query?

Tags: excel, grouping, powerquery

I have a small database with a date column (e.g. 1/5/2019). Using excel with power query, I'm grouping these by months (a table for each month - e.g. Nov 19, Dec 19, Jan 20, Feb 20 etc). **Right now I have a separate query for each month (which is 36 queries for 3 years)** and I load each query into an excel sheet. But I it takes unreasonable amount of time.

The idea is to have these months distinguishable from one another at first glance. The request was to **have months separatedly formated as "little tables", eaching having a header with "January" etc.**

Is there a more clever way to do it? From a single query using a parameter maybe?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needn't grouping date by month in PQ. You should have all data in single query and download it in Data Model. Then create Calendar Table and you will be able to use wide variety of DAX time-intelligence functions.